# Energy in the Ising model for liquid-gas transition

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, phase-transition, ising-model, critical-phenomena

I am teaching myself statistical mechanics using the lecture notes of Professor Leonard Susskind. I am confused about a statement 'reducing $h$ reduces the density' at page $555$. I know the statement is right from intuition since $h$ changes $\bar{\sigma}$. However, I cannot see it from the formulas. And I get more and more confused when I reread this chapter. Which represents the fluid? The particle or the void position?

In the last chapter, it's said we can use an empty lattice with particles in or out to represent the liquid-gas transition. At default, the spins are pointed down with energy $-1$. The energy of the system can be written as

$$
E=-j\sum_{links}\sigma_n\sigma_m+h\sigma_n.
$$

Then it stated that when we introduce a particle into one void position. We need an energy of

$$
8j+2h.
$$

I have no problem with these numbers. Nevertheless, after I reread this part several times, it seems if we introduce a particle, the energy of this system increases. How can this ever be possible to suck any particles? On the other hand, $h$ here when it's increased can create a lower energy empty position.

This lower energy empty position could be related to lower chemical potential. But I don't know how this two be connected because whatever lower energy it creates, if you introduce a particle it increases the energy. Moreover, you lower more and introducing particles increase more. With the energy increased, as it increases higher when you increase $h$, I think it might reduce the density other than reducing $h$.

And more confusing thing is that the empty lattice is the ground state. Thus if I decrease the temperature, till at $T=0$, the systems has no particle at all.

Comment: Are you familiar with the spin interpretation of the Ising model (and the behavior of the model)? Then, it's a trivial matter to translate the results: you identify, say, $+$ spins with particles and $-$ spins with empty spaces. Of course, decreasing $h$ increases the number of $-$ spins, thus of holes in the lattice gas interpretation, which lowers the density of the gas. Maybe have a look at Chapter 4 of [this book](http://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook), where this is done carefully; see, in particular, Section 4.8.

Comment: Thank you, I'll read the book you referred. If the density is about gas, it makes more sense.